# Tag synonym: [rt] -> [request-tracker]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Five questions have [rt](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rt) tag but actually they can be tagged as [request-tracker](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/request-tracker) too.

Source: https://www.bestpractical.com/rt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syonymized and merged.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​